# Save form input data as draft when having related tables affected

Tags: laravel, forms

I am working on creating an event form in Laravel project, which is complex and affects multiple related tables like events, tags, tickets, sponsors, speakers, targeted audience,...etc

I want to add a "save as draft" feature to this form since the user might not finish filling and submitting the form in one shot.

I searched and found a solution which is adding the column (draft) to events table
but now, how can I handle this on multiple related tables?
and if I have not null columns on the table that haven't been inserted yet, they cannot pass when saving as draft.

Any advice?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All fields can be made nullable

Only update other related forms when the user fills out all options

or Bind the filled-in items to a model, and when saving as a draft, serialize and save it to another temporary form.

Save only when the user actually submits